# value get released from variable when value is float number

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber

I am facing such strange issue right now, I am trying to implement calculator in my project the demo. The place I want to implement is ARC enable and my project ARC disable everything is working perfectly in that demo its working perfect in my project tOO but when i try to do operation on float values then my application crashes says EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1.... below is my code

_currentValue and _previousValue are like this in .h file

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSNumber* currentValue;  
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSNumber* previousValue;
```

in my .m file there are 2 methods where i face problem

```
- (NSString *)calculateValueToString:(NSString *)valueString ForType:(enum State)type{

    _currentValue = [numberFormatterFormal numberFromString:valueString];

    NSLog(@"%@",_currentValue);  //whatever number i input it get prints here

    [self calculateValue]; // this method get called
    state = type;          

    if (state != Equal){
        _previousValue = _currentValue;
         NSLog(@"%@",_previousValue);  // get print 
        _currentValue = @0 ;
    }

     NSLog(@"_previousValue%@",_previousValue);   // get print 
    NSLog(@"_currentValue%@",_currentValue);      // get print
    return [numberFormatterFormal stringFromNumber:_currentValue]; 
}

- (void)calculateValue{ 

    switch (state) { 
        case Plus:
            _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_previousValue doubleValue] + [_currentValue doubleValue]];
            break;
        case Minus:                        //GET ONLY EXECUTE ONLY IF OPERATION IS -

              NSLog(@"%@",_currentValue);  // it has value 

   --->>>>>>> HERE APP CRASH         NSLog(@"%@",_previousValue);   // app crashes here

            _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_previousValue doubleValue] - [_currentValue doubleValue]];

               NSLog(@"%@",_currentValue);  
              // THIS ALL WORK PERFECTLY IN THAT DEMO WHICH IS ARC ENABLE 
            break;
        case Multiple:
            _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_previousValue doubleValue] * [_currentValue doubleValue]];
            break;
        case Divide:
            _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_previousValue doubleValue] / [_currentValue doubleValue]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize and release previousValue and currentValue?

Comment: do not initialize and release them

Comment: But if ARC is disabled, you need `retain` and `release` for memory management.

Comment: properties are retain look i have put .h file property (retain,nonatomic) NSNumber* currentValue;  
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSNumber* previousValue;

Comment: Nikhita i will release them ones everything works perfectly

Comment: How many of `NSLog`s out of 4 get executed in your first method? btw you might want to put `state = type;` before you call for `calculate` method.

Comment: all get print when operation is other than equal if its equal then it will not go in if condition

Comment: question is edited check please

Comment: Are you releasing the `_currentValue` variable somewhere?

Comment: i am not releasing it any where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing your instance variables directly,   and using manual reference counting. This isn't going to work.

All of the memory management is done in the synthesised accessor methods, so you *must* use the property accessors, e.g:

```
self.currentValue = ....;
```

Never

```
_currentValue = ...;
```

Or you will be bypassing all of the retain / release calls that the accessors are doing for you.

Comment: but some where i heard that in ios we dont need to synthesis property we can use _currentvalue directly correct me please if i going on wrong direction

Comment: And sir one more question everything is working perfectly but problem only arise when operation is minus and values are float why so? why am i not facing problem in my every operation?

Comment: You don't need to synthesize properties, and the ivar is created for you, but if you're using manual reference counting you _must_ use the property accessors. As for your second question, probably due to the fact that NSNumber uses singletons for low value integers, so you don't have a releasing problem.

Comment: i understand sir but then why its not working only for float values and only when i do operation of minus? except that everything works fine please make me understand i am so confuse

Comment: right now i need to go sir but i will reply you whenever i will come back thank you so much for explanation and please tell me why its working for other operation there also i am using _currentvalue and _previous values its so strange that i am not facing problem there as you have said i know you will clear my doubt

Comment: I can't really explain any further than I did in the second part of my last comment, and that's just a guess.